# Checking if a vector belongs to ANY cyclic code

Tags: vector-spaces, coding-theory

Let $y$ be a vector in $V(n,q)$. How can I check if y belongs to ANY cyclic code over that space, other thank the cyclic code contating all of $V(n,q)$?

Comment: You just need to check whether the cyclic code generated by $y$ is the trivial code.

Comment: Can't it belong to a code it does not generate? I'm trying to get a condition rather than a method of checking

Comment: any cyclic code to which it belongs, has a subcode generated by it.

Comment: Patrick's right. So you should turn $y$ into a polynomial $y(x)$ in $\Bbb{F}_q[x]$, and calculate $\gcd(y(x),x^n-1)$. If this has degree $>0$, then $y$ will belong to the non-trivial cyclic code generated by that gcd. You can calculate the gcd with Euclid's algorithm.